# If statement for detecting autofilter, even when nothing has been filtered

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I've had a search around for this but havn't found anything yet. To clarify, I'm looking for a simple if statement for applying an autofilter if none exists, or do nothing if there is one already in place.

I thought the solution would be:

```
If ActiveSheet.FilterMode = False Then
    Selection.AutoFilter
end if
```

but this only detects filtered data. If a filter is already in place and you execute this line...

```
Selection.AutoFilter
```

The filter vanishes, and my code has a bad day. Is there a simple solution to this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You were close:

```
If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False Then Selection.AutoFilter
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between `.AutoFilterMode` and `.FilterMode`.

`.AutoFilterMode` becomes True if the AutoFilter drop-down arrows are currently displayed on the worksheet.

`.FilterMode` becomes True only after the drop-down arrows are used to create a filter, or after filters are created in VBA code.

And so `.AutoFilterMode` must become true before `.FilterMode`.

Comment: that clears up a lot thank you